# Best way to Compare String of 10 numbers

Tags: java

I'm comparing two Strings of min 8 digits and max 10 digits.  If 10 digits, will include two leading 0's.

Strings can be entered by user as either:

`String s1 = "0077889966";`

or

`String s1 = "77889966";`

String to compare should typically be in `"0077889966"` format as this is how they are stored on the object.

What is the best way to compare two Strings of min 8 digits and max 10 digits?

I've tried converting to a number with `Integer.valueOf(s1)` however doesn't seem to be working correctly.  Not sure I should use `BigInteger` here or something else.

```
String s1 = "0077889966";  // or "77889966" as input
//Convert to number
Integer num1 = Integer.valueOf(s1);

//loop over Array of objects.  On match, print current object.
for(int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    String s2 = objs[i].getStringOfNum(); // "0088224477" 
    Integer num2 = Integer.valueOf(s2);
    if(num1 == num2){
    System.out.println(objs[i]);
} else {
    System.out.println("no matches");
    }
```

Currently, I get all "no matches" in console.  There are as many "no matches" printed as there are objects in the Array. Nothing matches when at least one should so I question the precision of converting Strings into large numbers.

Comment: This is an error: `if(num1 == num2){`.  It should be `if (num1.equals(num2)){`

Comment: This certainly worked and I should've known better at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to compare with strings, then you can prepend zeros to the front of your input to make sure it is always 10 digits.

```
String s1 = "77889966";
int length = s1.length();
if (length < 10)
{
    s1 = "0000000000".substring(length) + s1;
}
System.out.println(s1);
```

Then you can compare the object string to formatted input string:

```
for(int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    String s2 = objs[i].getStringOfNum(); // "0088224477" 
    if (s1.equals(s2)) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the two first digits are supposed to be 0 we can ignore any difference in length and directly compare the integer values of the string

```
static boolean isEqualNumbers(String first, String second) {
    try  { 
        return Integer.valueOf(first).equals(Integer.valueOf(second));
    } catch (Exception e) {
       return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the strings char by char in linear time:

```java
/*
  Returns:  1 if s1 > s2
            0 if s1 == s2
           -1 if s1 < s2
*/
public static int compareNumStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    // Make sure s1 is the longer of two strings
    if (s1.length() < s2.length())
        return -compareNumStrings(s2, s1);
    // Compare strings char by char
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    int lenDiff = s1.length() - s2.length();
    while (i1 < lenDiff) {
        if (s1.charAt(i1++) != '0') return 1;
    }
    while (i1 < s1.length()) {
        char c1 = s1.charAt(i1++);
        char c2 = s2.charAt(i2++);
        if (c1 > c2) return 1;
        if (c1 < c2) return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The second loop can be replaced by `return s1.substring(lenDiff).compareTo(s2);` if you like more succinct code. But when I aim at efficiency, I prefer more explicit code.

Comment: This is better than solutions which convert to integer, but there are a few issues with the implementation: Minor: 'c1' and 'c2' should be declared inside the while loop.  Bigger: Because the values can be swapped, the '-1' and '+1' return values may need to be swapped.  In any case, this is a much faster strategy.

Comment: Good catch, Thanks. Fixed. @ThomasBitonti

Answer (score 0):

Pad both Strings with `0`'s, so that they both become 10-character-long and can be easily compared.

If you're using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```
String padded = com.google.common.base.Strings.padStart(str1, 10, '0');
```

Or use String.format() in order to pad:

```
String padded = String.format("%1$10s", inputString).replace(' ', '0');
```